# File-Drop mechanism of some associated filetypes (.zip, .rar,...)

Tags: c++, winapi, drag-and-drop, ole, file-type

I would like to know , how file manager like WinRAR manage it to enable Drag & Drop support for their archive file (when a file is dropped on a .rar-file it opens and optionally WinRAR adds the file to archive).

Image for demonstration:  [image]

EDIT: After some comment, I want to clarify what I want to do (see Image):

1. Files of a certain data type accept a Drop request (.rar).
2. Dropping the file (.txt) result in a Shell-call that passes the name of the **dropped file (.txt)** as well as the name of the **file which accepted the Drop** (.rar).
3. The application registered to the file type is called, both filenames are provided to it in the command line.

Comment: I don't know what's weird about [Drag and Drop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96826a87.aspx), but that's a common way to enable drag and drop support for any application.

Comment: Yeah it is just unusal and challenging if the drop target is not the executable or the active window.

Comment: It doesn't say so in your question either. If you want to know, how to integrate with the shell (i.e. explorer.exe), you should at least mention explorer in your question. As written, it takes a lot of reading-into, to understand, what you are really asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a **Shell Drop Handler**.

This is a COM object which implements the `IPersistFile` and `IDropTarget` interfaces.  `IPersistFile` will tell you which file is being dropped on.  `IDropTarget` will give you an `IDataObject` to tell you which files/data are being dropped.

The documentation is here:

- [How to Create Drop Handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144165.aspx)

Comment: Ok, this look promising, I will look into it.